# How can I disable auto ease in

Tags: interpolation

So we all know its there, and we all know how to fix it, but adding the extra steps to have to change the interpolation on every new animation just plain sucks. To be honest I don't find this feature useful as a default at all because more times than not we have to correct for it.

Is there an option somewhere to turn auto ease in off? (I personally think this should be the default and should require user to turn it on if they want it).

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of opinions,... most movement in animation and in real life starts from zero, then reaches a certain speed, then decelerates and stops gradually, constant linear motion can feel robotic.

In the user preferences you can set the default interpolation for New F-curves
to one that suits your needs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oops! I probably should have looked a little closer before posting but if anyone wants the answer:

User Preferences -> Editing tab: In the 3rd column from the left Under "New F-Curve Defaults" change Interpolation to what ever you want (Linear for constant, Bezier for ease in, or any of the other options which I will leave you to explore their function.)